# HTML tags not being rendered when data is inserted using CKEditor

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, ckeditor

I'm building a simple blog system with PHP, mysqli, jquery, AJAX and CKEditor editor.

When I format my text in the CKEditor (or TinyMCE, doesn't matter) and save it in my database everything is OK. However when I print the text back, surprisingly, my browser won't render the html tags and displays them as plain text!

I have checked and I don't have any kind of CDATA in the page, that might cause the issue.

Here is how it renders:

How it renders

However, when inspecting the issue with FireBug, I noticed a lot of spaces before the  tag is being printed! If I just make a small change in the spaces (Remove one or add another), then the browser will render the tags and display the text properly!!

Can you guys help me with this issue? It's really weird.

Comment: Some code for context would be great

Comment: Where is it escaped? If you look in the database, does it looks like html?

Comment: thanks @AndreasFurster . yaah, database field's value looks like html. when retrieve the value and want to show this value in front end and the tag like <p>,<br/> are not rendered.

Comment: if you `console.log()` your ajax data... Is it still not escaped?

Comment: @AndreasFurster, "<p>\r\n এশিয়ান গেমস ক্রিক...ন দুটি করে উইকেট।</p>\r\n"

Comment: How are you adding the received html to your document?

Comment: public function addNews($news_title,$news_sub_title,$news_source,$description,$thumb_name,$video_link,$published_date,$offset,$category_ids,$user_id) {

        $response = array();
  $pub_date = new DateTime($published_date);
  $pub_timestamp = $pub_date->format("U");
  $adjusted_pub_timestamp = $pub_timestamp + $offset*60;
  $pubs_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $adjusted_pub_timestamp);
  $publish_date = new DateTime($pubs_date);
  $published_date = $publish_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: $date = new DateTime();
  $created_date = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  
  $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO news(news_title,news_sub_title,news_source,description,news_image,video_link,published_date,created_date,updated_date,created_by,updated_by) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

  $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssii", $news_title,$news_sub_title,$news_source,$description,$thumb_name,$video_link,$published_date,$created_date,$created_date,$user_id,$user_id);  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  if($result){
   $news_id = $stmt->insert_id;
  }

Comment: $stmt->close();
  // Check for successful insertion
  if ($result) 
  {       
   $category_ids_array = explode(',', $category_ids);  
   if(count($category_ids_array)>0){
    foreach($category_ids_array as $category_id){

Comment: if($category_id != ''){  
      $this->addCategoriesNews($news_id, $category_id);
     }
    }
   }       
   return USER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;  // news successfully inserted
  } 
  else 
  {             
   return USER_CREATE_FAILED;   // Failed to create news
  }

    }